# I get this error when running the very simple java code

Tags: java

I get this error when compiling the code
"possible loss of precision"
What am I doing wrong!?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Assignment2
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int number=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number"));
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(number));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning a double value to a integer variable. It is complaining that the 'fractional parts' of a double value might be lost in the process.

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language. You have to be explicit with your conversions.

Comment: ^both correct, you should be using a double as the local variable instead of an integer. The sqrt function takes a double as an argument anyways, there is no need for the conversion to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare `number` as `double` like those answers, but if you really want `number` to be an `int` then cast the return value:

```
int number = (int) Double.parseDouble(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a double value to a int value, that is the reason(since double can store larger values and have decimal part it could lead to lose of data)... I think you need to assign the value returned by `Double.parseDouble()` to a double variable

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Assignment2

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        double number = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Enter a number"));
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(number));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here:

```
int number = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number"));
```

You should change type of number to `double` in order to prevent losing of precision